# Adding item to DropDownList at runtime from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In the front-end I have something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MyBadDropDown" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" OnChange="valueChanged()" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and in the back-end as a test code I have something like this:

```
    Dim listCol As New ListItemCollection
    listCol.Add(New ListItem With {.Value = ""})

    listCol.Add(New ListItem With {.Value = ConvertValue(Of String)("640", "0"), .Text = "New Item"})
    Me.hidValeuForThis.Value = "640"


    Me.MyBadDropDown.DataSource = listCol
    Me.MyBadDropDown.DataBind()
```

But when I hit that part of the code, the new item does NOT get added to the dropdown items until there is post back... so it doesn't automatically show up in dropdown items.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified it a bit and it seems to work.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"   
    DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value" Height="16px" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The code behind...

```
Public Class _Default
Inherits Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim listCol As New ListItemCollection
        listCol.Add(New ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty))
        listCol.Add(New ListItem("New Item", "640"))
        listCol.Add(New ListItem("Another Item", "950"))
        DropDownList1.DataSource = listCol
        DropDownList1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Debug.Print(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
    Debug.Print(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString)
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list that is not local, and add the item to this list. After you assigned this list to the dropdown list as Datasource, you can add item to the list or remove them and the dropdown follows.

Comment: OK I tried your suggestion. Still no luck : So I took out Dim listCol As New ListItemCollection from the method and put it in top of class as global if that's what you meant.